# Merge multiple nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

I have an unknown number of dictionaries with an unknown set of keys, e.g.:

```
d1 = {'job': {'data': {'id': 'string'}}}
d2 = {'job': {'data': {'title': 'string'}}}
d3 = {'job': {'metadata': {'date': 'string'}}}
d4 = {'user': {'id': 'string'}}
```

I want one combined dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
    'job': {
        'data': {
            'id': 'string',
            'title': 'string'
        }
        'metadata': {
            'date': 'string'
        }
    },
    'user': {
        'id': 'string'
    }
}
```

The built-in `update` doesn't give me what I want:

```
>>> combined = {}
>>> combined.update(d1)
>>> combined.update(d2)
>>> combined.update(d3)
>>> combined.update(d4)
>>> combined
{'job': {'metadata': {'date': 'string'}}, 'user': {'id': 'string'}}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/1015595) sounds really close to what I want, but it has the same result:

```
>>> {**d1, **d2, **d3, **d4}
{'job': {'metadata': {'date': 'string'}}, 'user': {'id': 'string'}}
```

That question specifically asks for a union, but that doesn't look like a union to me. What am I missing?

Comment: If the keys are static, could be as easy as `{**d1['job']['data'], **d2['job']['data']}` to merge the inner dicts

Comment: The keys aren't static, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic attempt that responds to your question using a `recursion`, a `generator` and `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce


def union_nested_dicts(a, b):
    a_keys = list(a.keys()) if isinstance(a, dict) else []
    b_keys = list(b.keys()) if isinstance(b, dict) else []
    for k in set(a_keys + b_keys):
        if not isinstance(a.get(k, {}), dict) or not isinstance(b.get(k, {}), dict):
            if a:
                # Or: yield from a.items()
                yield k, a.get(k, {})
            if b:
                yield from b.items()
        else:
            tmp = dict(union_nested_dicts(a.get(k, {}), b.get(k, {}))) 
            yield k, tmp


a = {'job': {'data': {'id': 'string'}}}
b = {'job': {'data': {'title': 'string'}}}
d3 = {'job': {'metadata': {'date': 'string'}}}
d4 = {'user': {'id': 'string'}}
out = reduce(
    lambda left, right: dict(union_nested_dicts(left, right)),
    [a, b, d3, d4]
)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
{
    'job': {
         'data': {'id': 'string', 'title': 'string'},
         'metadata': {'date': 'string'}
     },
     'user': {'id': 'string'}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU you want to merge dicts with similar keys **and** update for different ones.

Here's a simple attempt using the new syntax of python 3.9:

```py
def nested_union(a, b):
    new_dict = a.copy()

    for key, value in a.items():
        if key not in b:
            new_dict |= b  # new_dict.update(b)
        elif not isinstance(value, dict):
            new_dict = a | b  # {**a, **b}
        else:
            new_dict[key] = nested_union(value, b[key])

    return new_dict
```

I suggest you unit test the provided code as my tests were based in your example. A extension with *args would improve readability during usage.

Comment: Thanks for adding the syntax for earlier versions in comments.

Comment: I found some surprising behavior: if the first argument is an empty dictionary, the result is an empty dictionary. Reversing the arguments produces the desired result.

Comment: More weirdness - try merging all of these: `[{'a': {'1': 1}}, {'a': {'2': 2}}, {'b': {'1': 1}}, {'b': {'2': 2}}`. Somehow the outer `a` key gets lost.